# JSP alignment of image

Tags: jsp, servlets, web

What is the best practice of aligment images on JSP page, I want to make center a pic but **align** attribute has following options:

- top
- middle
- bottom
- left
- right

Should I use css or.. what ?

What I want to do:

[image]

Comment: Formatting on a JSP is not any different than an HTML page. A JSP is just a way to generate an HTML page. This is really a question about HTML and CSS and not about JSPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advisable approach is:

```
<body>
  <!--Menu-->
  <!--body-->
  <!--footer-->
</body>
```

It changes according to the requirement also.

To includes the jsp fragment you can use the jsp tag lib as:

```
<jsp:directive.attribute name="title" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" />
<body>
 <div style="padding-top: 50px;">
  <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/menu.jspx"/>
  <jsp:doBody />
  <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/footer.jspx"/>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't need header i.e banner & menu and footer?